# materializecss pagination with currentpage link enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, materialize

I found a pagination plugin for Materializescss UI, [Github link](https://github.com/mirjamsk/materialize-pagination), which is working great, additionally, I want to extend this plugin to set the currPage value, and it should be highlighted(active)

For example [image]

Here I have 2 type of paginations, First page, last page everything is working fine. Just assume I am reloading the page and I am in currently 4th page, once page get reloaded I lost the current page, I know currently there is no option to set the current page, Just I want to achieve it with static variable

```
    var CurrPage = 4;
    $('#pagination-long').materializePagination({
        align: 'center',
        lastPage: 10,
        firstPage: 1,
        currentPage:CurrPage,
        useUrlParameter: false,
        onClickCallback: function(requestedPage) {
            console.log('Requested page from #pagination-long: ' + requestedPage);
        }
    });
```

[Codepen workout](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZvYKvO)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the urlParameter provided by the plugin?

```
$('#pagination-long').materializePagination({
            align: 'center',
            lastPage: 10,
            firstPage: 1,
            urlParameter: 'page',
            useUrlParameter: true,
            onClickCallback: function(requestedPage) {
                console.log('Requested page from #pagination-long: ' + requestedPage);
            }
 });
```

You can play with it here https://codepen.io/alojzije/pen/PEqQBx?page=4

However, to actually have the `page` parameter changing, you'll need to open the pen in DEBUG mode because only then the rendered code is not in an iframe [DEBUG link](https://s.codepen.io/alojzije/debug/PEqQBx/bZAQWyBWOJvM?page=6)

Comment: But i am using ajax :(